# Using canvas in Tic-Tac-Toe in Java

Tags: java, canvas, awt

I am trying to make a Tic-Tac-Toe game using `awt` in Java but I am facing some problems. Actually, it's a work in progress and some of its parts are not complete.

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class tictactoe extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
    public Canvas c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9;
    Panel p;
    Button b;
    tictactoe()
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        b=new Button("New Game");
        add(b,BorderLayout.SOUTH); // Button to reset the game
        p=new Panel(new GridLayout(3,3,5,5)); // Canvas objects in GridLayout
        c1=new MyCanvas();
        c2=new MyCanvas();
        c3=new MyCanvas();
        c4=new MyCanvas();
        c5=new MyCanvas();
        c6=new MyCanvas();
        c7=new MyCanvas();
        c8=new MyCanvas();
        c9=new MyCanvas();
        p.add(c1);p.add(c2);p.add(c3);
        p.add(c4);p.add(c5);p.add(c6);
        p.add(c7);p.add(c8);p.add(c9);
        add(p);
        setBounds(400,100,310,310);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        new tictactoe();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
          // Work in progress
    }
}
class MyCanvas extends Canvas
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawLine(0,0,120,100); // This is the part where I am facing the problem
    }
}
```

The problem is that I want to call `drawline()` in a single `Canvas` element but the `drawLine()` method draws a line in all the nine canvas elements.

Comment: Every canvas instance is of type `MyCanvas` and it's paint method draws the line you described.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything else is working correctly (even though creating a seperate canvas for each of the squares is not how I would approach this), you should be able to do this:

```
Graphics g = c1.getGraphics();
g.drawLine(20, 100, 120, 100);
```

Where you get the graphics object of the canvas individually and then `draw()` to it. Where the above code is inside of your main class.

The reason why lines are being drawn for all canvases is that this method is in the default paint method for `MyCanvas()` and thus executed when each `Canvas` object is created.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply but i didnt get what u said...i mean i am using drawLine() method but its in paint() method, not in constructor of MyCanvas class so how could it effect all of them?

Comment: Sorry I misread the code. You're basically overriding the default `paint()` method, so when the canvas paints itself, it will always draw the lines. The approach I suggest alleviates this, by moving the draw calls outside of the class.

Comment: you mean to say that i am supposed to call drawLine() method in main method and the overridden paint() method will not have any code?

Comment: Yeah, that is how I would do it. The only time you would specify calls to draw objects in the class itself is if each canvas had something that was drawn universally to all canvases.

Comment: but how would a canvas object call drawLine() method.??

Comment: It's not. You would get the graphics object from the respective canvas.